# Difference between running commands locally vs using SSH to make remote commands

Tags: command-line, ssh, shell, java, ksh

I am trying to SSH into a remote machine, and run a .ksh file on a that machine to run a Java program.

If SSH into the machine with a tool like Putty, and run this command:

```
cd /folder/folder/examples; ksh runexample.ksh NameOfClass methodName
```

The Java program runs its full course, sending some data, putting it into an outside database, and displaying a response.  However, if I try to SSH into the machine from the command line on another machine, like so:

```
/usr/bin/ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx.x "cd /folder/folder/examples; ksh runexample.ksh NameOfClass methodName;"
```

The program doesn't execute fully.  It doesn't give me any errors, but it simply returns notification that the class files were loaded successfully, the first line of the Java program is displayed, then it quits without sending a request or receiving a response.

What are the differences in my two approaches? Any idea of what would be causing this?

Comment: You can try fork it, maybe putty just sends command and quits ssh; try `/usr/bin/ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx.x "cd /folder/folder/examples; ksh runexample.ksh NameOfClass methodName &"`

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is exiting before the java command finishes, and killing all the subordinate processes.  You need to either rewrite your script so that it waits for the java program to complete, or else rewrite it to allow processes to survive beyond exit.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had accidentally included a semi-colon after "methodName" in the SSH command.  Interesting to me is that this launched the application, displayed the first line, and then quit without any error messages!